# Am I allowed to set Bounties on meta sites?

Tags: support, bounties, per-site-meta

When I visit SE questions, I can see a "start a bounty" link, but I can't see it in meta sites? Am I not allowed to set bounty on meta (either here or on per-site metas)? Does it even make sense to do so, since per-site metas don't offer rep?

Comment: Related: [Can't post bounty on a per-site child meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78264/cant-post-bounty-on-a-per-site-child-meta) and [Bounty-like feature on metas](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78264/cant-post-bounty-on-a-per-site-child-meta).

Comment: @Martin Your second link is a repeat of the first. Here's the right link: [Bounty-like feature on metas](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/231215)

Comment: Thanks for the correction @SevenSidedDie. I was a bit surprised to notice that your comment did not add that question to the [linked questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/77658). Is it because you used [//url syntax](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/280355)?

Comment: @Martin Interesting… Must be, yeah. I guess that's a big they'll have to fix if they want to move to protocol-relative URLs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it here, but *this is not a per-site meta*, it is a standalone entity.

You cannot create bounties on per-site metas.

Answer (score -1):

Judging by the [faq](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq) there is no bounty option. If would not really make sense anyway.

**UPDATE**

Seems that I'm wrong about it. There are featured questions.

Comment: I didn't find a mention in that faq. Can you give a quote?

Comment: Well that is actually what I meant. I can't find a word about bounties so I guess that there is no bounty option but apparently I'm wrong as there are featured questions around. SO it seems that I'm clueless.

Comment: Just because it's not mentioned on FAQ, does not mean that the option isn't there. Also, 'featured' doesn't necessarily mean that the question has a bounty on it.

Comment: There are featured questions which don't have a bounty?

Comment: @Tshepang is referring to a different "featured" concept, Octavian. Overloaded term, as it were. As a question class, "featured" means "has a bounty on it". But there's also a special moderator-only tag "featured" that can be put on questions on Meta sites to advertise on the main Q&A. Note that this latter one doesn't have *anything* to do with the "featured" tab.

Comment: @GraceNote Thanks for the info. Did know that.