# Can I create bounties on THIS meta's questions?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, bounties

I know that [the per-site meta systems aren't allowed to have bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77658/am-i-allowed-to-set-bounties-on-meta-sites). However, this meta has always been allowed to have them, at least, I thought. For example, I wanted to set a bounty on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92286/why-is-the-bounty-button-in-an-inconsistent-location) (which is ironically about bounties), but the button to add one doesn't appear.

Was an intentional change made here to disallow bounties or is that a bug?

EDIT: To clarify, there's no button. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of potential bug]

Comment: If this is a trick to get us to bounty up your question while trying to reproduce this, I am going to be sooooooooooooooooo impressed.

Comment: @Shog9: Lol -- I just want to put one on it myself, but I can't. If you put one on my question to try to reproduce it then you've not reproduced it ('cause you had to see the button to add one).

Comment: Oh, so you don't even see the button? I misread your question then; perhaps "the button doesn't appear to add one" could read, "the button to add one doesn't appear"...

Comment: @Shog9: Agree that's better written. Done.

Comment: @Shog9: Also added a screenshot -- now there's a screenshot inside of a screenshot... maybe I should screenshot this page...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had a bounty on a deleted question - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58423/so-retag-request-gnu-flex-flex-lexer

I'll update our auto-bounty-award task to remove and refund any bounties it encounters on deleted questions.

Answer (score 2):

Either you already have a bounty on another question (that's the correct answer to this question most of the time) or you have a "broken" old bounty on a question that something unusual happened to.

Comment: Can that be fixed then? There's only [one active bounty right now](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured) at it's not mine.